# How to fix Windows 8 Start screen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I have install k9 web security then Found this thing. Look like something goes wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

This happen after reboot. I am not sure if something else make this issue. Do someone know how to fix it.

Comment: It appears the version of `K9 Web Security` you have installed does not support Windows 8.  You have `Version 4.4` instaleld correct?  There revision history does not specifically list Windows 8 as being supported except one entry that **MIGHT** suggest it.

Comment: I download it on 1 March 2013. Last time its' work fine. I have check the page and it's support Win8 :)

Comment: I suggest you uninstall `K9 Web Security` and see if this problem goes away.

Comment: I reinstall it by downloading new version. things are fine now @Ramhound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem Cause I install K9 Web security. I am sure because I haven't installed anything when I installed it.

How I solve this :-

I download the setup again from the site. I install it again (without uninstall old, maybe this way you don't need to set up it again).

Now if you sign-out and logged once again you got it working.

Thanks to  Ramhound for his comments to fix this trouble.